# invalid_scope: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds is not a valid audience string

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-oauth, gspread

I'm trying to use OAuth2 and gspread to use Python to manipulate Google Sheets. However, I keep running into this error:

> invalid_scope: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds is not a valid audience string.

Initially, I had the scope as a list, however, I saw another answer on StackOverflow saying that the scope should be a space delimited string instead. I tried changing it over but the error still occured.

Here is my code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ' '.join(['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("SpreadsheetExample-bec536232207.json", 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://googleapis.com/auth/drive')

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("test").sheet1

print(wks.get_all_records())`
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is very clear: `spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` is not an API scope.

If you want to request permission to access Google Sheets files, use one or more of the API scopes listed in the Sheets REST API documentation:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing

These are tabulated nicely there:

> **Scope**  Meaning
>   **`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`** Allows read-only access to the user's sheets and their properties.
>   **`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`**  Allows read/write access to the user's sheets and their properties.
>   **`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`**    Allows read-only access to the user's file metadata and file content.
>   **`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`**    Per-file access to files created or opened by the app.
>   **`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`** Full, permissive scope to access all of a user's files. Request this scope only when it is strictly necessary.